# Are there any practical examples of the migration from legacy system to cloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, cloud

Are there any practical examples of the migration from legacy system to cloud?

For example, some website has migrated their system to GAE/AWS, and during the migration, they met different problems which are new to them, and then they figured out how they could solve the problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Gae does NOT compare with AWS. GCE does

Answer (score 0):

Lots of examples from AWS.  See this answer: [Are there any big names running on the cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560012/are-there-any-big-names-running-on-the-cloud?rq=1)

Here is a case study from Reddit moving to AWS: http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/reddit/